# Nginx basic auth not working with some urls

Tags: nginx

I had configured nginx basic authentication. That is working fine with all urls. Now I added a new one /jenkins(.*) but authentication is not working on this. I am not able to access /jenkins url with or without password. Nginx server configuration:

```
    server {
            listen 8080;
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location ~ ^/analysis/ {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.195:8070;
                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .

        location ~ ^/jenkins(.*) {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.21:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        }

    }
```

Comment: When you say not working, what exactly is happening ? Do you see any error ?

Comment: @ben5556 I am not able to access /jenkins url using existing username and password. Other urls are working fine.